# Why does the type of the first parameter of setsockopt differ between client API and kernel?

Tags: c, linux, sockets

In the client API, like lksctp-tools:

```
int setsockopt (int __fd, int __level, int __optname,
     __const void *__optval, socklen_t __optlen);
```

In Linux kernel source (referenced by "include/linux/net.h"):

```
int (*setsockopt)(struct socket *sock, int level,
     int optname, char __user *optval, unsigned int optlen);
```

The client API uses integer type FD value for first parameter, but the kernel receives a pointer to a `struct socket` for first parameter.

How to explain this difference? Does another library exist?

Comment: Inside the kernel, the rules are different, and instead of needing a nice simple integer, the kernel can deal with different pointers.  It is more convenient to use the structure inside the kernel; it is more convenient to use the file descriptor in the client.  It is a common trick.  The important thing to remember is that the client APIs are not seen by the kernel and the kernel APIs are not seen by the client.  They're completely separate.  No; there isn't another library — it is not reasonable to claim that the kernel is a library.

Comment: I found a code in kernel source, `static struct socket *sockfd_lookup_light(int fd, int *err, int *fput_needed);` (linux/net/socket.c)

Comment: Yes, … and … was it interesting?

Answer (score 0):

User APIs often mask internal structures to users, they provide only **opaque types**. A file descriptor is such , you only see an integer but internally it is associated to some structured data.

The kernel should be consistent so we don't want users to be able to modify such structures by themselves. So, the kernel is only accessible through some special calls (system calls). Theses calls are specials as the execution crosses the border between the user space and the secure kernel space. You are not able to access kernel space directly, you must pass through predefined *portals*.

Then internally, the kernel does whatever he wants, it has its own internal APIs that you can't use, but he offers you a way to ask him a service.

Think of what happens when you request a ID card: you fill a form and give it to some administration (you make an system call), but you never know what really happens behind the scene (internal tricks in the kernel).